# Handling intermediate service layer errors in Python

Tags: pyqgis, wms, wfs, error-handling

I have a QGIS project with a WMS (`QgsRasterLayer`) and a WFS (`QgsVectorLayer`) layer.
These layers might encounter random issues, e.g. missing network access or parsing errors.

How can I be notified about them using signals?

### What I found so far

#### WFS

`QgsVectorLayer` has a [`raiseError`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.raiseError) signal. This is just it's [`QgsVectorDataProvider`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider.raiseError)#s raiseError signal re-emitted.

This seems to fire e.g. when a WFS cannot be parsed so I think this is sufficient for this kind of layer.

#### WMS

For [`QgsRasterLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterLayer.html) there is no such signal. I tried these possibly related signals:

- `QgsRasterDataProvider`.[`statusChanged`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRasterDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsRasterDataProvider.statusChanged)
- `QgsDataProvider`.[`dataChanged`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsDataProvider.dataChanged)
- `QgsDataProvider`.[`notify`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsDataProvider.notify)

but none of them got emitted on errors like

```
WMS(1): Download of capabilities failed:
```

or

```
WMS(1): Tile request max retry error. Failed 3 requests for tile 0 of tileRequest 6 (url: https://...)
```

How can I catch those?

Comment: out of interest does the QgsVectorLayer raiseError signal fire on failure to download the capabilities. or just failing to parse a feature response

Comment: From my tests so far: Both.

Comment: could you use it for a WMS GetCapabilities (to test for failure to fetch)

Comment: What do you mean? The errors might happen at any stage, imagine a WMS stopping to working during an Atlas export.

Comment: You could have it as a test as part of error handling, but it would only be of help when trying to connect initially I assume.   A WMS going offline in the middle of a series of requests is unlikely to be due to unavailable capabilities; but I see no difference here to a WFS behaviour; it's unlikely that you'd suddenly not be able to parse a WFS response part way through paging a set of results or because of failure to fetch a capabilities.

Comment: Imagine being on an unstable network connection.

Comment: Bit like my current network :(